# How to add prefix before category url in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite

My all categories are assigned in default category. Now I have urls like that:

```
www.magentoShop.com/category_name/
```

And I want to add prefix "something" it should look this way:

```
www.magentoShop.com/something/category_name/
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Create a category called 'something' and place all of your categories within that? It's URL slug would be added as the prefix you're looking for.

Comment: So any idea how to achive this in magento 2 ? for some reason this is the rare question

Comment: Here you can find some guidance : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/193312/56372 I have created custom router for adding prefix to url using plugin to all products and categories page