# How to write a test for custom router and plugin in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, testing, unit-tests, integration-test

I have created a module in magento 2 for adding prefix to the url of all product and category.

here is the snippet code for the router :

```
   /**
     * Match route pages for handling cp / ip
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $pathInfo= trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $requestUri = trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/');

        $requestUriParts = explode('/', $requestUri);
        array_walk($requestUriParts, function (&$value) {
            $value = trim($value);
        });

        $pathInfoParts = explode('/', $pathInfo);
        array_walk($pathInfoParts, function (&$value) {
            $value = trim($value);
        });


        if ($requestUriParts[0] == $this->prefixCp || $requestUriParts[0]==$this->prefixIp) {
            // remove the cp or ip
            $requestUriFinal = '';
            unset($requestUriParts[0]);
            foreach ($requestUriParts as $r) {
                $requestUriFinal .= $r . '/';
            }

            // remove cp or ip
            unset($pathInfoParts[0]);
            $pathInfoFinal = '';
            foreach ($pathInfoParts as $p) {
                $pathInfoFinal .= $p . '/' ;
            }


            $request->setRequestUri($requestUriFinal);
            $request->setPathInfo($pathInfoFinal);
        } else {
            // No route math here
            return;
        }

        /*
         * We have match and now we will forward action
         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
```

How to test the logic in this `match` function ? 
and also for the plugin :

```
/**
 * this will modify the class Product in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php
 */
class ProductPlugin extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    /**
     * Returns request path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetRequestPath(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return 'ip/' . $result ;
    }
}
```

I just want to test a simple test case where my custom route handle the request. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be concerned is the `match` function, I think it would be better to breakdown this function into smaller one so that it can be easily tested.

Here is the snipped code :

```
   /**
     * Match route pages for handling cp / ip
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $requestUri = trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/');
        $pathInfo= trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $result = $this->getCustomPath($requestUri, $pathInfo);
        if (is_array($result)) {
            $request->setRequestUri($result['requestUri']);
            $request->setPathInfo($result['pathInfo']);
        } else {
            // No route match here.
            return;
        }

        /*
         * We have match and now we will forward action
         */
        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $pathInfo
     * @param string $requestUri
     *
     * @return array of two strings | null
     */
    public function getCustomPath($requestUri, $pathInfo)
    {
        $pathInfo= trim($pathInfo, '/');
        $requestUri = trim($requestUri, '/');

        $requestUriParts = explode('/', $requestUri);
        array_walk($requestUriParts, function (&$value) {
            $value = trim($value);
        });

        $pathInfoParts = explode('/', $pathInfo);
        array_walk($pathInfoParts, function (&$value) {
            $value = trim($value);
        });

        // remove cp/ip for requesrUri and pathInfo
        if (!empty($requestUriParts[0]) && in_array($requestUriParts[0], $this->prefixes) || !empty($pathInfoParts) && in_array($pathInfoParts[0], $this->prefixes)) {
            $resultRequestUri = $this->removePrefix($requestUriParts);
            $resultPathInfo = $this->removePrefix($pathInfoParts);

            return [
                'requestUri' => $resultRequestUri,
                'pathInfo' => $resultPathInfo
            ];
        }


        return [
            'requestUri' => $requestUri,
            'pathInfo' => $pathInfo
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parts
     * @return string
     */
    private function removePrefix(array $parts)
    {
        $result = '';
        unset($parts[0]);
        foreach ($parts as $index => $r) {
            if (sizeof($parts) == $index) {
                $result .= $r;
            } else {
                $result .= $r . '/';
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

As you can see from above code I've created two smaller functions which return the values that change the request that being passed to the router. so I can easily test those two function without having to worry about the `match`.

And this is the unit test code :

```
class RouterTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory |\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $actionFactoryMock;

    private $testCases = [
        // test 0
        [
            'requestUri'=>'ip/woman/on/top/someproduct.html',
            'pathInfo'=>'ip/woman/on/top/someproduct.html',
            'expected'=>'woman/on/top/someproduct.html'
        ],

        // test 1
        [
            'requestUri'=>'cp/men/top-jacket/product.html',
            'pathInfo'=>'cp/men/top-jacket/product.html',
            'expected'=>'men/top-jacket/product.html'
        ],

        // test 2
        [
            'requestUri'=>'test/one.html',
            'pathInfo'=>'test/one.html',
            'expected'=>'test/one.html'
        ],

    ];

    protected function setUp()
    {

        $this->actionFactoryMock= $this->getMock(
            'Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory',
            [
                'create'
            ],
            [],
            '',
            false
        );
    }

    /**
     * Test match function for the router
     */
    public function testMatch()
    {
        $router  = new Router($this->actionFactoryMock);
        foreach ($this->testCases as $testCase) {
            $result = $router->getCustomPath($testCase['requestUri'], $testCase['pathInfo']);
            $this->assertEquals($testCase['expected'], $result['requestUri']);
            $this->assertEquals($testCase['expected'], $result['pathInfo']);
        }
    }
}
```